# CSS gradient to create two different color design

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I am trying to create a specific shape with specific color to keep it as a background. I successfully created gradient color that I want but I am struggling with getting shape right.

Here is what I have done and what is am trying to achieve,

My Work :

[image]

Expectation :

[image]

**Code :**

```css
.grad {
  height: 400px;
  width: 900px;
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #62e6a5 50%, #9ae7ba 50%, #9ae7ba 52%, #d1f5de 52%, #d1f5de 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="grad"></div>
```

I am open to use any other method as long as it is only one 'div'. I don't want to use two different div which are causing many issues in responsive design. I tried using **clip-path** but that too did not help because of the nature of the design.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use pseudo-elements to achieve the offset effect you're after.

Comment: I tried using pseudo-elements but could not make the shape I want because I have never used them before. That's the nice suggestion. Let me try again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple gradient then adjust dimension and position to obtain what you want:

```css
.grad {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(110deg, #62e6a5 50%, #9ae7ba 50%, #9ae7ba 52%, #d1f5de 52%, #d1f5de 0) 0 0/100% calc(100% - 10px) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(110deg, #62e6a5 52%, transparent 0) 0 100%/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="grad"></div>
```

Comment: Looks perfectly fine.Thanks. The only problem I found was with responsiveness which is a huge concern for me.

Comment: wow that was so quick and easy solution.Thank you. I wish I would have thought of it. I want to learn linear-gradient more deeply, would you please provide some reference document which explains all the arguments for the gradient so I can learn it myself?

Comment: @Developer123 you won't find 1 reference with everything but i would say that you have two main part ... the gradient that you can consider a simple backgroud-image THEN the other property i use after, background-size, background-position that allow you to have what you want so you need first to learn what is inside the gradient then learn how to adjust size/position to obtain what you want. I advise you to check this website https://css-tricks.com/search-results/?q=gradient where you will find many good thing .. you can also check some of my previous answers as i did a lot with gradient :)

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will definitely check out the link you have provided and your previous answers.

Comment: @Developer123 here is a link where you can easily find them https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a8620333%20gradient .. you can also search within SO for gradient question/answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pseudo-elements` like `:before` and `:after`

```css
.grad{
  position: relative;
  height:200px;
  width:450px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #62e6a5 50%, #9ae7ba 50%, #9ae7ba 52%, #d1f5de 52%, #d1f5de 0);
}

.grad-new{
  position: relative;
  height:200px;
  width:450px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #62e6a5 50%, #9ae7ba 50%, #9ae7ba 52%, #d1f5de 52%, #d1f5de 0);
}

.grad-new:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 3%;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 55.6%;
  background: #62e6a5;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
.grad-new:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 44.4%;
  background: #fff;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="grad"></div>
<div class="grad-new"></div>
```

Comment: I tried to do with pseudo-elements before posting this question but I failed. However, it was so thoughtful of you to put the white line to cover right part. Excellent. Thank you. The only problem I found with the solution is responsiveness.